# android multiline text and ellipise end

Tags: android

i have set maxlines 3 in my textview and i need ellipse end ,i have set it but not working how can i do this ?

```
  <TextView
                android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/descriotionTextViewPaddintTop"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/descriotionTextViewPaddintLeft"
                android:textSize="@dimen/description"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 />
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, then this is a bug in android. [[LINK]](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2254).

Refer [[this code]](http://code.google.com/p/android-textview-multiline-ellipse/) for a solution.